# How to transit data between Java applet and ASP.NET web page?

Tags: java, asp.net, applet

Is there a way to pass data from Java applet to aspx page and vice-versa?

Comment: *"Is there a way to pass data from Java applet to aspx page and vice-versa?"*  Yes there is, but since a knowledgeable person could write a complete chapter (or a short book) on the subject, this is 'too broad' for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [websocket.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

For the java part, I have a good experience with this library:
http://www.ning.com/code/2010/03/introducing-nings-asynchronous-http-client-library/

On the Windows side, there's a problem that websocket is supported since Windows 8. I don't know if it will suffice or if there's some workaround